# Creating a custom MCBrowserViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

Is there a way to create a `UITableView` housing the same information found in an `MCBrowserViewController`? My current code only allows a standard view to be pushed that is not in the same design as my app:

```
self.browserVC = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"chat" session:self.mySession];
[self presentViewController:self.browserVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11):

1. Set your View Controller as the delegate to `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` and `MCSession` (i.e. `<MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCSessionDelegate>`)
2. Create a property for your `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` (and `MCSession`)
3. In `viewDidLoad` (or whichever trigger suits your pattern) of your View Controller:

   ```
   _myPeerID = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];
   _mySession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:_myPeerID];
   [_mySession setDelegate:self];
   _browser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc]initWithPeer:_myPeerID serviceType:@"connectme"];
   [_browser setDelegate:self];
   [_browser startBrowsingForPeers];
   ```
4. Implement the `- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info` method as so:

   1. Add every found peer into an array for the data source of your `UITableView`. Typically you'd get the `peerID.displayName`.
   2. Call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: The WWDC 2013 session titled "Nearby Networking with Multipeer Connectivity" discusses this in the "advanced" section of the talk.  It also describes what you need to do in the various delegate methods.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [MCSessionP2P](https://github.com/shrtlist/MCSessionP2P.git), a demo app that illustrates the ad-hoc networking features of `MCSession`. `SessionController` conforms to `MCSessionDelegate`, `MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate` and `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate` and acts as the datasource for a `UITableView`. The app advertises itself via Wi-Fi or Bluetooth and programmatically connects to available peers, establishing a peer-to-peer network.

Answer (score 0):

Yazid's answer was working for me. Next step, to connect to a peer that was found during `startBrowsingForPeers` use

```
_browser.invitePeer(peerID, toSession: _mySession, withContext: nil, timeout: 30.0)
```

(SWIFT notation here)